# Rename multiple folder names based on names contained within a txt file

Tags: batch-rename, bulk

I have over 100 folders with names I would like to change. I have all the current and desired folder names in a txt file, with current name first and the desired name second, seperated by a space; e.g. EUO159815 1_BG_TL.

Is there an script or a good way to do this?

Many thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: Yes. You could write a script to do this. I would suggest using powershell but batch would work as well. This site however is not a code writing service.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Kenji unfortunately proposing an answer as an edit won't go through; so [your python script](https://pastebin.com/u1tX6vaF), though well-intentioned may not be seen. What would be better is an edit that would bring the question back into an openable state, so that you can post your answer

Comment: @EBGreen I wasnt intending for anyone to write a script for me. Maybe I should have written "batch renaming tool" instead of "script", my apologies. As it is I got what I needed, many thanks, Chris

Answer (score 2):

You can use Advanced Renamer and it's List Method mentioned here: https://www.advancedrenamer.com/user_guide/method_list

> List method
>
> This is a very simple method. There are no fancy features in this method. To use it, you have to type in the new filename of every file in the list or load the new names from some external source.
>
> You can use the Load List and Save List buttons to load and save lists of filenames. You can load a file that contains a previous Advanced Renamer file list (a list saved by List -> Save List), but you cannot load that list with List -> Load List.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Done @DavidPostill and thanks for the warm welcome. :)